# If $g(x,y)$ is continuous at $(x,y)$, is it always possible to find $f(x+y)$ such that $g = af$ with $a$ being real?

Tags: functions, solution-verification, continuity, transformation

Is true that for any continuous function $g$ at $(x,y)$, there exists a function $f(x+y)$ such that

$$g(x,y)=a f(x+y)$$

with $a$ being a real scalar?

In other words, is it always possible to find a function $f$ (having only one argument $=x+y$) and it represents another function $g$ (which has two arguments $x$ and $y$) up to a scalar multiple?

I am not sure if it is always possible, sometimes possible, or never possible. Also I am not sure if this is a kind of translation.

For example, if  $g(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2$, what should be $a$ and $f$?

---

Your help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Possible when $g=0$ (take $f=0,a=1$). No possibel when $g(x,y)=x$ (assming that your domain is $\mathbb R$)

Comment: Note that if $g(x, c-x)= af(x+(c-x)) = af(c)$ in this case. That means, that $g$ needs to be constant along all lines with slope $-1$. So in general this is not true.